Type narrowing using early returns to infer an object contains a property
I am writing a type guard for an object. I use early returns to keep the indentation readable, but the example is contrived.
I understand that typescript narrowing still has a lot of holes, with more narrowing logic being added every release. However, it is still difficult to know what is user error and what is still not supported by TypeScript narrowing.
I have an example below that I thought should infer a property exists on an object, but perhaps my logic is not correct.

Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'.

Can someone please clarify why the property isn't inferred at the commented point?
type Example = {
  a: number
}

const guard = (example: unknown): example is Example => {
  if (
    example === undefined ||
    example === null ||
    typeof example === 'string' ||
    typeof example === 'number' ||
    Array.isArray(example)
  ) {
    return false
  } 
    
  if ((example as Example).a === undefined) {
    return false
  }

  // I expect narrowing to infer example as {a: unknown}
  // due to the if statement above

  // TS Error; Property 'a' does not exist on type '{}'.
  if (typeof example.a !== 'number') {
    return false
  }

  return true
}

const example: unknown = {
  a: 2
}

const result = guard(example)

I also tried
if (a.hasOwnProperty('a')) {
  return false
}

and
if (Object.hasOwn(example, 'a')) {
  return false
}


example.a === undefined is incorrect if you are trying to identify whether or not example has a property named a. For example, the object { b: undefined } has b defined. It's just that it has a value of undefined. Instead, you should be using the in operator to check if keys exist: "a" in example. That would solve your current problem, too, as TypeScript knows what you are trying to do.

Firsty, this is a complex way to write this guard function.
I would use this instead:
type Example = {
  a: number
}

const guard = (example: unknown): example is Example => {
  if (example === null || typeof example !== 'object') {
    return false
  }
  
  return ('a' in example && typeof example.a === 'number');
}

const example: unknown = {
  a: 2
}

const result = guard(example);
console.log(result);

You used a type assertion and made a undefined check on casted variable. This does not narrow the original variable example
Compare:
function chceckX1(x: unknown) {
  if (x === '123') {
    // x: '123'   
  }
}

function chceckX1(x: unknown) {
  if (x as string === '123') {
    // x: unknown, no narrowing on x   
  }
}

function chceckX2(x: unknown) {
  const z = x as string;
  if (z === '123') {
    // z: '123'   
  }
}

Thus, you could modify your code by introducing a variable
// Do not use, complex and confusing
const guard = (example: unknown): example is Example => {
  if (
    example === undefined ||
    example === null ||
    typeof example === 'string' ||
    typeof example === 'number' ||
    Array.isArray(example)
  ) {
    return false
  }
  const exampleCasted = example as Example 
  if (exampleCasted.a === undefined) {
    return false
  }

  if (typeof exampleCasted.a !== 'number') {
    return false
  }

  return true
}

Note that while this correctly checks the shape of input object, there is no narrowing going on - exampleCasted is Example, which may be incorrect.
TS allows to compare numbers with null. See disallow comparing to null and undefined unless they are valid cases in strict null mode #11920
This check has no effect on exampleCasted type.
